# Get articles from TYPO3 news extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want to realize an image slide, that show the last 3 news from the news extension on it.

So - I'm obvioulsy new to TYPO3 - I somehow need to fetch the data from the news extension.

I would prefer doing it inside the new extension, so I guess - from what I know so far - it should look somehow like this

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

$orderRepository = $objectManager->get('Tx_News_Extension_Path_To_Articles'); // don't know path

$articles = $orderRepository->find(3, BY-DATE, DESC); // don't know the command

$this->view->assign('articles', $articles);
```

I head of another way by doing it through TypoScript. Maybe I could use this:

```
lib.news_list < lib.news
lib.news_list {
            action = list
            switchableControllerActions.News.1 = list
}
```

Would be glad to get some advise.

Chris

Comment: It should be possible to just use the plugin (list view) that comes with the extension and use a custom template. You can have multiple templates for the plugin and switch between them in the plugin settings when editing the plugin. Check the extension's manual and Google for details.

Comment: I use the news extension (not tt_news), the extbase/fluid one, do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, I mean that extension - [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/TemplateSelector/Index.html) the manual describes how to have multiple templates for the list view of  the extension.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a function like this to your repository:

```
public function findLastByDate($amount){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->setLimit($amount);
    $query->setOrderings(array(
        'date' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
    ));
    return $query->execute();
}
```

And call it in your controller:

```
$articles = $this->orderRepository->findLastByDate(3);
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction. This sounds nice. But I can't see, where this targets the news-model or the news-extension?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what you mean.
If you use a query in a repository, the repository always returns the regarding model. Therefore the NewsRepository returns $amount NewsModels in a QueryResult, that you can use like this:
`foreach($articles as $article){
      print($article->getTitle());
}`

PS: If you use $query->execute(true) you get the raw query result without the Models

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. But where do I specify the source of the items. I obviously need to tell the query, from where to fetch those items - in my case from the news extension and in there only the news from folder with `ID=??`.

Comment: There are two ways to do this.
First you can set the persistence.storagePid by typoscript.
Or you use Typo3QuerySettings.

Comment: Sorry. I obviously have to be more specific. >our code tells TYPO3 to fetch something, how much of it `amount` and how you want those results to be ordered `orderings`. But you do not specify, from where these items should come from. Shouldn't it be in the query as well. Please do me a favour and show me how that works.

Comment: You don't need to set up anything in this Query anymore. Because of $this->createQuery() (=NewsRepository->createQuery) the query will always Return news objects